# How to extract XML value of a record in SuiteScript (NetSuite)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

How do you extract a value that doesn't show up on the records browser, but shows up on the xml=t of a record?

For example, I'm working with a Work Order record and trying to extract Quantity Built and Quantity scrapped, this doesn't show on the records browser but shows in the XML as:

```
<built>5000</built>
<scrapquantity>0</scrapquantity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use those field with the .getField or setField functions on the record object

Answer (score -1):

I ran the following in a browser console and was able to get the string version of the xml text.  I know strings aren't ideal for parsing; but it's a start.

```
require(['N/https'], function(https){
  var headerObj = {
    name: 'Accept-Language',
    value: 'en-us'
  };
  var response = https.get({
    url: 'https://1234567.app.netsuite.com/...&id=12345&xml=T',
    headers: headerObj
  });
  console.log('response.body', response.body);
});
```

Comment: You can use the N/xml module to convert a string to XML.
            var xmlDocument = xml.Parser.fromString({
                text: xmlString
            });

After you have the document, you can use the methods of the XML module objects to get the value you need.

Answer (score -1):

Two ways which I can think of

1. Try loading the record using record.load() API. And then try accessing the desired value using record.getValue().

```
var someRecord = record.load({
   type:'',
   id:'',
   isDynamic: true
});

var builtValue = someRecord.getValue('built');

var scrapQuantity = someRecord.getValue('scrapquantity');
```

2. You can create a Saved Search on this record and fetch the values by either loading the record or including the record in your script.